# Multiple Media Queries penalize efficiency?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a site with some elements modularized, so how all its javascript and html is modularized, also I would like that all css was in the same place, and not mixed with other css of the page.

The consequence is that the media queries blocks will be repeated for every module (with different rules, obviously, but the same block conditions to be triggered). So the question is simple: This will penalize the efficiency of the css interpretation? Some test or links related with this issue?

Thank you in advance.